# Excel Pivottable refreshing (2010 vs 2016) - why not working in 2016, but working in 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have strange problem and I am not sure if it's problem with newer excel version or newer version works in other way and I need to make links in other way?
In our company users having Microsoft Office Home & Business 2016 , and 2010.

While I am refreshing pivot table with source to another file on server disk (we don't have exchange and sharepoint) - it is refreshing normally on 2010 version. While updating data in Pivot excel is doing that in background.

But the problem is on 2016. When I try to refresh data I got message: **"Can't open pivottable source file '.... .xlsx'"** , so it is not refreshing.
When I open the source file - it's blocked by some user (but in fact nobody has it opened). I supose that when I open the file with pivot table, excel somehow opens source file, and then it cant refresh it? The funny thing is that when i have this source file opened in read only I CAN refresh the pivot table, but lets say, i want to put new data in the source - i cant save it under same name because i have it in read only... so i couldnt chech how my pivot table will look with changes.

I tried to find the reason why it's working in different way on Excel 2016. On 2010 everything is ok.
My only conjecture is that 2016 is more adjusted to work on sharepoint, cloud or something? Is there some solution to make it working the same way in 2016 as in 2010?